# how to copy file from docker container over to Jenkins

Tags: python, docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I am new to building and running dockers. So I have a jenkins pipeline setup where I have a stage which runs a python file. I have created a docker to run this python file.Using commands

```
    sh "docker build -f create-abc-Dockerfile -t create-abc ."
    sh "docker run create-abc python create-abc.py $name $abc ${abcDescription}"
    getDetails = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "cat abc_details").trim()
```

where create-abc-Dockerfile is my docker file and create-abc.py is my python file.
create-abc-Dockerfile contains

```
     FROM python:3.8-alpine3.10
     COPY create-abc.py .
     RUN pip install requests
     CMD ["python", "create-abc.py"]
```

My python file performs some action - calls an API and some parts of the response in a file "xyz_details"

The above piece of code in Jenkins pipeline runs correctly calling my python file executing the API, but it cannot access xyz_details file. It says file not found.

I read a couple of posts and tried a few methods

1. Instead of running the build, I changed CMD to RUN in docker - but my python file is paramterized, and it passes dynamic values. So this method does not work for me
2. Tried this method

```
    docker cp <containerId>:/file/path/within/container /host/path/target
```

My code :

```
    sh "docker cp create-abc:/xyz_details ."
```

where create-rfc is my container (I am using the tag name provided above when building the docker)
But I am getting the following error

```
    + docker cp create-abc:/xyz_details .
     Error: No such container:path: create-abc:/xyz_details
```

All I want to do is, run the python file, write the result to xyz_details, read this xyz_details file again in Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: Firstly, think about handling containers, performance etc. Are you killing it after run? Building each time docker with python is not a good idea... jenkins docker plugin will do the job for you (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/). Volumes are mounted automatically so you will always have your results in the workspace. docker.image('yourImage').inside() { create-abc.py }

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use volumes. You basically need to run the docker container and attache a volume for the destination path (where the files will be generated). and then you will have access to the files from the host machine.

```
sh "docker run -v $PWD/myfiles:/dir/path/within/container create-abc python create-abc.py $name $abc ${abcDescription}"
sh "cp -r $PWD/myfiles /to/path"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i copy file from docker container to local in jenkins through pipeline

```
  sh """
          docker cp  container_name:/app/test-reports ./test-reports
     """
```